# Finding cardinality of a set which sum of its elements equal to an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_m$ be a set such that
$$
A_m = \left\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)\in \mathbb{N}^n |\, a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n = m \right\}
$$
Can we calculate cardinality of $A_m$, i.e Card(A_m) = |A_m| = ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on here.  Try googling stars and bars...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29 (this is really easy to apply if $0\in \mathbb{N}$ and mostly easy if not).

Comment: These look like your compositions of $m$ into $n$ parts, and much is known about them. Google "integer composition"